# Send notification on Time/Date from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm trying to figure out how to make my application send a notification on the specified date/time which it retrieves from my database.

[image: example]

it does not need to do anything complicated like a pop-up/sound notification it just needs to send a simple message.

my code so far.

```
    SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Goeli\Desktop\Feedr OIS\DateTimePlanner2\DateTimePlanner2\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        timePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        timePicker2.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
        DisplayData();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Planner(Name, Date, Time) VALUES(@Name, @Date, @Time)", connectionString);
                connectionString.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", timePicker2.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectionString.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Planned");
                DisplayData();
                //ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide a name");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Cannot have duplicate name");
        }
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {
        connectionString.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.Planner", connectionString);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        connectionString.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Planner WHERE Name=@Name", connectionString);
        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {                   
                connectionString.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connectionString.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(" Successfully Deleted");
                DisplayData();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide the name to delete");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }       
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the fastest and simplest solution I would propose to use

1. A Timer that raises events, for example, every minute (or second, depends on granularity you need to achieve) and reads a schedule - collection of dates\times with messages.
2. A separate thread (or a timer) that reads (polls) your database every X seconds and maintain the schedule (adds\removes events).

Some simple synchronization needs to be involved.

As an alternative you can use 3rd party libraries, like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler). For more heavyweight solutions if you need consistency across many instances of you application, consider [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: If a hosted environment (with limited functionality) there is a free web service called ATrigger.  Here you can schedule web calls.  Full-disclosure, there can be drift of up to a couple of seconds